# After deleting a web page it still shows in the search engines, why?

Tags: http, web, tags, seo, search-engine

I am new to this but I was asked to help out at work with modifications of our web site, one of the first things I was asked to do was remove the page for a product we no longer stock. I removed the page and links so when you are on the site you do not have the option to even see the product.

So before changes where made you would navigate to "http://example.com" when pressing on lighting you would navigate to "http://example.com/lightbulb" showing the inventory.

Now with the changes in place there is no way to navigate to the product because it was removed when I type "http://example.com/lightbulb" in my url I get 404 page can not be found which is the desired behavior.

But when performing a Google search on "light bulb", Google is listing http://example.com/lightbulb as a an available domain with the same summary as before. Obviously when navigating to it, you get the 404 error, page can not be found,

What did I forget to do, so that search engines no longer list http://example.com/lightbulb with the summary?

Comment: What is the response code of your 404 page? If the 404 page returns a `200 Ok` the search engines will not remove it from their index. Also, does the URL change for the 404? If so, then the search engine has no idea that the 404 is meant for the original requested page

Comment: How long has it been since you made the change? The search engines do not update instantly - you may need to wait for the next crawl. It's worth checking your 404 page actually returns a 404 HTTP response code though. Also, do you have a `sitemap.xml`? That might need updating too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google robots does not crawl the website everyday but after a certain interval.

I would suggest you to  create an account on **Google Webmaster tools** and check your website's indexing status.

Moreover using the tool, you can also make a request to Google to re-index your website.

Hope it helps you some extent.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time for the search engines to update. In the meantime, you can add a "HTTP-301 Permanently Moved" redirect-script in the /lightbulb directory, by creating an 'index.php'-file and adding this code:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/', true, 301);
exit;
```

It will tell browsers and search engines that the new URL for your page is `http://example.com/`

Comment: Not a good idea to redirect to home page. It should be a 404, not a redirect.  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2409439?hl=en